# VisualBasic.NETで他アプリケーションを操作する方法

Tags: vb.net

はじめまして！

今VisualBasic勉強中で悪戦苦闘しています。
タイトルの通りVB.NETでVBアプリケーション自身から起動した他アプリケーション（例：コマンドプロンプト）を操作（コマンド送信→結果取得）をしようとしています。

```
    AppActivate(プロセスID)
    SendKeys.SendWait("dir\{Enter}")
```

、、みたいな感じで操作が可能なのですが出来ればウィンドウ自体を表示したくありません。

上記の方法だとウィンドウがどうしてもアクティブになってしまいます。

結果の取得も最初はコマンドプロンプト画面のコピーを取ってVBアプリがクリップボードの内容を参照するみたいな事を考えていたのですが同様の事情で私の望む動きにならないと思っています。

どなたかお助け頂けますでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします！

Comment: 真の目的がファイル一覧を取得することなのだったら `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles` が最短で、コマンドプロンプトを開くのは目的に対して超遠回りなわけで。真にやりたいことは何かを補足してくれると幸いっす。

Comment: @774RR 　コメントありがとうございます。　別に目的を隠している訳じゃなくてVisualBasic.NETのフォームアプリケーションの中にコマンドプロンプトを収めたいのです。　イメージとしては[Command Prompt Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14908/Command-Prompt-Control)のような感じです。　ただしこのコントロールではコンソールアプリケーションは実行出来ないのです。

Comment: ＠774RR  私的には遠回りではなくその事自体が目的なのですが、そのココロは既にDOSアプリケーションが利用されている環境があり、そのPCでWindowsフォームアプリケーションを新たに作成するに辺りMDIインターフェースの子ウィンドウの一つとして今まで使っていたDOSアプリケーションが使えると便利だからです。　答えとして十分でしょうか？　よろしくお願いします。

Comment: [コマンドプロンプト（cmd.exe）のフォーム埋め込み](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/12614/%E3%82%B3%E3%83%9E%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%83%B3%E3%83%97%E3%83%88-cmd-exe-%E3%81%AE%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0%E5%9F%8B%E3%82%81%E8%BE%BC%E3%81%BF)が参考になるのでは？

Answer (score 2):

例えば、こんな感じ

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Diagnostics

Module Sample
    Sub Main()
        Dim myProcess As Process = new Process()

        myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true 'ウィンドウを作らない
        myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"
        myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false
        myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true
        myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true

        myProcess.Start()
        Dim sr As StreamReader = myProcess.StandardOutput
        Dim myStreamWriter As StreamWriter = myProcess.StandardInput

        myStreamWriter.WriteLine("dir") 'コマンドを標準入力として書き込み
        myStreamWriter.Close()
        Dim returnvalue as String = sr.ReadToEnd() '標準出力を文字列で読込

        myProcess.WaitForExit()
        myProcess.Close()
        '動作チェックでファイルへ書き込む
        Dim file As StreamWriter = new StreamWriter(".\\out.txt") '結果をファイルとして書き込み
        file.WriteLine(returnvalue)
        file.Close()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: サンプルコードまで頂いてありがとうございます。　お手数をお掛けしてしまったのにこういう事を言ってしまうのは誠に申し訳なかったのですが私がやりたいのコマンドプロンプトをリダイレクトを介することなく操作したいのです。ちょっと忘れたのですがここの過去質問でコンソールアプリケーションの中には出力先がコンソールかリダイレクトかで振るまいを変える物があると知りました。　あくまでも出力先をコンソールとしてコンソールアプリケーションを操作したいのです。

Comment: 以前書いたコードをちょっと修正しただけなので気にしないでいいです。するとやっぱり`SendKeys`を使うことになるのかな。

Answer (score 1):

既に起動しているプログラム（この場合はコマンドプロンプト）を操作しないとダメですか？
自分でコマンドプロンプトを起動して希望する動作をさせる、ほうが圧倒的に簡単ですよ。
http://dobon.net/vb/dotnet/process/processwindowstyle.html
http://dobon.net/vb/dotnet/process/standardoutput.html

Answer (score 0):

コンソールウィンドウを非表示にして、なおかつ標準入出力のリダイレクトも行わないとなると、SendKeysは使えませんね。

SendKeysはアクティブウィンドウに対して操作するAPIですので、ウィンドウを非表示にしているアクティブではないウィンドウには使えません。SendMessage APIを使用してコントロールすることになるかと思います。

ウィンドウの非表示については、[コマンドプロンプト（cmd.exe）のフォーム埋め込み](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/12614/%E3%82%B3%E3%83%9E%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%83%B3%E3%83%97%E3%83%88-cmd-exe-%E3%81%AE%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0%E5%9F%8B%E3%82%81%E8%BE%BC%E3%81%BF)にある方法でWindowハンドルを取得後、ShowWindow APIで非表示にできるはずです。